Best question to promote to LAN?
I'd like to promote a top question to the LEGO Ambassador Network (LAN) in order to get more recognition for both that question and our community. If you aren't familiar with the LAN, it's a community made up of a representative from each major LEGO fan organization (LUGs, blogs, forums, etc) along with the staff of the LEGO Community Engagement team.
With that audience in mind, I thought it would be best to nominate questions here that we believe would benefit most from this sort of exposure, and then I'll post the one with the most votes to the LAN.
Please include both a link to the question you'd nominate and a brief description of why so that we can understand your thought process behind promoting it.

Could you clarify what kind of questions we should be looking for? Do they have to be unanswered questions or are we trying to highlight some of the best questions?

Honestly, I wasn't really sure what sort of question would be best, which is part of why I thought it would be helpful to float this to the community and see what we come up with. I don't think the question needs to be unanswered necessarily, but I think it should be a question that could benefit from better answers to encourage participation.

Not directly related, but I've raised an issue about the [tag:featured]  tag not updating the community bulletin.

Considering I wasn't sure what question best represents I've gathered a few questions based on certain criteria. 
Best Viral Question
How much usage can a LEGO piece take before it loses its 'clutch power'?

The most upvoted and one of the most viewed question on our site. A great example of a "What if...?" complete with a investigative answer that shows dedication to the LEGO Hobby by pcantin. 
The question made it to the front page of Reddit. As well as being featured on Discovery Channel - Daily Planet, Tested, WIRED (Japan), Smithsonian, Gizmodo, Kotaku, NBC News and many other websites!
On the day it was shared on Reddit the site had the highest pages views for a single day of all time (approximately 40k) and the fourth most new users in a day.
Unanswered Questions
In comparison to many other Beta sites LEGO Answers has a very high answer percentage (currently 97%). 
Of the 40 unanswered questions, half of them are tagged as EV3 questions. It would be good to get some more technical and experienced users who are familiar with EV3 programming to help answer some of these questions. Of course some of these questions aren't getting answers because they are more to do with software troubleshooting (something that would be better answered by LEGO Customer Support).
Here are some of the top voted Unanswered Questions that I might reccomend:

What is the difference between the plastic used in mainstream minifigs and the plastic used to make the popular collectable series of minifigs?
Where does the EV3 software store its crash reports?
Is there any way to find misplaced bricks in LEGO NXT Programming?


Thanks for the feedback. This makes me think I should just do more of an intro post including our top questions and some areas to get involved.
